# System of nested integral equations has multiple solutions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, integral-equations

The present question is related to this [Numerical solution of simple nested integral equations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/284681/numerical-solution-of-simple-nested-integral-equations). I want to solve the following system of integral equations numerically

$$q(J_0,T)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}\,\mbox{tanh}^2\left(\frac{z\sqrt{q(J_0,T)}+J_0 m(J_0,T)}{T}\right) dz$$

$$m(J_0,T)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}\,\mbox{tanh}\left(\frac{z\sqrt{q(J_0,T)}+J_0 m(J_0,T)}{T}\right) dz$$

and plot the values of $q(J_0,T)$ and $m(J_0,T)$ in the plane $J_0$ vs $T$. To do so I used the following code

```
precision = 20;
Maxit = 500;
accuracy = Round[precision/2];
funJq[T_?NumericQ, J0_?NumericQ, m_?NumericQ, q_?NumericQ] := 
  q - NIntegrate[
    1/Sqrt[2 Pi] Exp[-z^2/2] Tanh[
       SetPrecision[(Sqrt[q] z + J0 m)/T, 
        precision + 1]]^2, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> precision, AccuracyGoal -> accuracy];
funJm[T_?NumericQ, J0_?NumericQ, m_?NumericQ, q_?NumericQ] := 
  m - NIntegrate[
    1/Sqrt[2 Pi] Exp[-z^2/2] Tanh[
      SetPrecision[(Sqrt[q] z + J0 m)/T, 
       precision + 1]], {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> precision, AccuracyGoal -> accuracy];
qfunJ[J0_?NumericQ, T_?NumericQ, m_?NumericQ] := 
 FindRoot[funJq[T, J0, m, q], {q, 0.1}, MaxIterations -> Maxit][[1]][[2]]
mfunJ[J0_?NumericQ, T_?NumericQ] := 
 FindRoot[funJm[T, J0, m, qfunJ[J0, T, m]], {m, 0.8}, 
    MaxIterations -> Maxit][[1]][[2]]
```

Nevertheless the results for $q$ and $m$ are dependent on the initial value provided to FindRoot. Mathematically it is easy to see that the solution $q=0$ and $m=0$ is always available, but I expect, in general, non-trivial solutions.

As suggested in a comment I should solve for $q$ and $m$ simoultaneosly, is there a way to do it using Mathematica?

For completeness I post my results, which seems ok from the math point of view, but I want to be sure that they are ok and that my code didn't get stuck in trivial or spurious solution. I used the following code (in addition to the previously defined functions) to plot $m(J_0,T)$ and $q(J_0,T)$

```
data = Level[Table[{J0, T, mfunJ[J0, T]}, {J0, 0, 2, 0.1}, {T, 0.1, 2, 0.1}], {-2}];
magn = Interpolation[data];
Plot3D[magn[J0, T], {J0, 0, 2}, {T, 0.1, 2}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

which resulted in

[[image: <span class=]$m(J_0,T)$ in the $J_0$vs$T$ plane" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/He2q0.png)

and

```
data2 = Level[Table[{J0, T, qfunJ[J0, T, mfunJ[J0, T]]}, {J0, 0.01, 2, 0.1}, {T, 0.1, 2, 0.1}], {-2}];
over = Interpolation[data2];
Plot3D[over[J0, T], {J0, 0, 2}, {T, 0.1, 2}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

which resulted in

[[image: <span class=]$q(J_0,T)$ in the $J_0$vs$T$ plane" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vsvb2.png)

Comment: Might need to solve `{q,m}` simultaneously since they are interdependent.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed what I do in the code I provided

Comment: I'm seeing two separate calls to `FindRoot`.

Comment: The integral expressions are confussing:  Should you not specify $m(J_0,T)$ in the expressions where you have just $m$?  Also Procedure (1) is not very clear.  I assume you mean "in the $m\text{ vs. }q$ plane.  Not clear what you mean by "plane $q$.   
 Also what equation for m?  Maybe a plot would help, also if you included the expected range of the variables.

Comment: Ah, sorry @DanielLichtblau, I didn't understamd your comment, I'm a bit new in Mathematica. How can I solve for $q$ and $m$ simultaneously? Anyway I change the question since the original one made no sense.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @josh. I thought about it and I realized I made some mathematical mistakes. I apologize. I changed the question asking for a different (and maybe more correct than mine) way to numerically solve the system.